# Get history of groupmember/queue assigned to user

Tags: apex, soql, queue

I'm trying to check the history of groupmember assignments which was done to a specific user, I know that we have the GroupMember table to query the current assignments like:

Select Id, GroupId, Group.Name, UserOrGroupId, SystemModstamp from GroupMember where UserOrGroupId = 'userId' and Group.Type = 'Queue'

But the answer I would like to have is:

- this user was in the queue X yesterday, who assigned this queue to the user was user Y, today he is in this another queue because user Z removed the old queue and assigned this new one.

Is this possible? I wonder if we have some kind of history table who owns these informations.

Comment: at best -- SetupAuditTrail